# How do Unary operators work in C, you cannot pre increment zero

Tags: c, pre-increment, unary-operator

I am confused about how Unary Operators work in C for Ones Complement, Logical Negation and preincrementing.

Ones complement works against 0 like this:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    a = ~0;          // Ones complement
    printf("%d",a);  // prints as -1.
}
```

And logical negation works against 0 like this:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    a = !0;          // Logical negation
    printf("%d",a);  // prints as 1.
}
```

But Preincrement against 0 generates a compiler error:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    a = ++0;        //pre incrementing 0.  error: non-lvalue in increment
    printf("%d",a); 
}
```

Why don't all three work considering they are all Unary Operators?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The increment (`++`) and decrement (`--`) operators *modify* the thing that follows them. You can't modify a literal or a constant. In contrast, the `!` and `~` operators merely operate on a value, they don't then assign the result anywhere.

Loosely speaking, `++n` means `n = n + 1; n`. That is, "take the value of `n`, add one to it, ***write that value back to `n`***, and return the new value as the value of the expression." So `++0` would mean `0 = 0 + 1; 0`: "take the value of `0`, add one to it, ***write that back to `0`***, and return the new value as the result of the expression." Literals and constants cannot be left-hand values (you can't assign to them).

In contrast, `~n` means "take the value of `n` and apply a bitwise NOT operation to it, return the result as the result of the expression". `n` is unchanged, `~` doesn't write back the updated value to its operand.

So for example:

```
int n = 0;
int a;
a = ~n;
printf("a = %d, n = %d\n", a, n); // "a = -1, n = 0" -- `n` is unchanged
```

vs.

```
int n = 0;
int a;
a = ++n;
printf("a = %d, n = %d\n", a, n); // "a = 1, n = 1" -- `n` is changed
```

Increment (`++`) and decrement (`--`) are just different in that way than for `!` or `~` (or, I think, any other unary operator — at least, I can't immediately think of any others that modify their operand).

Comment: but how ~ its modifying the constant?

Comment: @jack: no, `~` is **not** modifying the constant. It's taking the value, operate on the value and return a new value. It doesn't change the thing it operates on itself.

Comment: @jack: It isn't. `~n` means "take the value of `n` and apply `~` to it, return the result as the result of the expression" (`n` is unchanged). In contrast, `++n` means "take the value of `n`, add one to it, ***write that value back to `n`***, and return the new value as the value of the expression." It's that bit that writes the result back to the operand that's different for `++` and `--`.

Comment: yeah i understood now so it performs these operations on RAM and store them back i really understood now after that line ++n=n+1 and ++0=0+1. thank you guys you both are great

Comment: @crowder can i add you on my msn or facebook is that allowed ? i got some good friends here i hope they help me to get me the problems i face through in c.

Comment: i want to be in contact with them can i add ?

Comment: @Jack, you still are missing something crucial: ++ *cannot* be used on constants or literals, therefore, what you said "++0=0+1" is not valid. It would been correct to say something like "int x = 0; ++x == 0 + 1".

Comment: @Coleman: He said he understands now. @jack: In terms of staying in touch, just post further questions here on StackOverflow. There are people here who are *dramatically* more knowledgeable than I about C (and even more so about C++, if you're going to go that route).

Comment: gosh i just made it you know i was hurry to leave so it just happened people here worry so much let me change it i was busy moms calling out for lunch so wait a minute i will change it

Comment: why people keep on giving me downvote did i do anything wrong ?

Comment: @jack: I don't know why people are downvoting. I will say that it helps when you use punctuation, capitalization, and complete sentences, both in questions and in comments. I mean *"gosh i just made it you know i was hurry to leave so it just happened people here worry so much let me change it i was busy moms calling out for lunch so wait a minute i will change it"* is pretty...stream-of-consciousness. :-) Also note that StackOverflow is not a discussion site. It's a Q&A site. See [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for the distinction.

Comment: cool ok i understand but truly and honestly and frankly I text to my friends on mobile and chat on facebook with friends. so I just got habitutated to it.i hope you guys understand it anyways but still i love it because they are people who gives me the answers sorry sorry i wont comment nomore sorry again i stop my discussion

Answer (score 4):

`++` and `--` don't just apply an operation to a value, they change the value itself. This behavior wouldn't make much sense on a literal.

The other unary operators that you refer to -- namely `~` and `!` -- do not change the value of their operand, they just perform an operation on its value.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to increment a literal value.  Since operation x++; is a synonym for x=x+1; this means you are trying to set a new value for 0, which is not a variable.